# Render MathJax in an SVG file

Tags: svg, mathjax

I have spent a few days on the following with no joy.

I wish to render Mathjax in an SVG file. I have no problem including it in a html file in an svg element using a foreignObject from the examples at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/_UMt3C7TIpQ/discussion, but I cannot get it to work in an svg file.

The code I am trying is as follows :-

```
<svg width="1960" height="1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<script type="text/javascript" src="MathJax-master/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-SVG"></script>
<g>
<title>Layer 1</title>
<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="50" id="svg_1" y="223" x="636" stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="0" stroke="#007FFF" fill="#000000">Hello World</text>
<foreignObject x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100">
   <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <div>
       \(\displaystyle{x+1\over y-1}\)
     </div>
   </body>
 </foreignObject>
</g>
</svg>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I do suspect the problem is with the line declaring the body element.

Answer (score 2):

A `<div>` tag is html so the `<body>` tag should be in the html namespace  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` rather than the svg namespace.

Your other mistake is that you're using html syntax for the script tag. SVG script tags use xlink:href instead of a src attribute. Fixing that gets us here:

```
<svg width="1960" height="1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<script xlink:href="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<g>
<title>Layer 1</title>
<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="50" id="svg_1" y="223" x="636" stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="0" 

stroke="#007FFF" fill="#000000">Hello World</text>
<foreignObject x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100">
   <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <div>
       \(\displaystyle{x+1\over y-1}\)
     </div>
   </body>
 </foreignObject>
</g>
</svg>
```

But when we do that we run into a bug in the mathjax library. It seems it expects to find html nodes in the document (check the Firefox Error Console). You'd have to contact the mathjax developers and get them to fix their bug to progress further.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't seem to make any difference, even leaving out the div's and/or changing svg to xhtml. The hello world still renders, but all that the foreignObject render is the unformatted text.

Comment: Ok, thanks for for the tip. I have posted an issue with the Mathjax github and will comment further once I have some feedback.

Comment: Ok, the final outcome is it cannot be done as I wanted it to be. It is not a 'bug' per se, but just not the way MathJax was designed to operate. They have marked it as "look into", so maybe onday it will be addressed. At the end of the day all work-around methods involve wrapping the svg file in an html file.

Comment: Just an update.... the MathJax developers closed the log on it, so it seems no further development will take place on this.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).