# tex-mml-svg.js:1 Uncaught Error: Unknown node type "body" while creating MathJax SVG

Tags: svg, mathjax

I try to create an SVG equation with MathJax according to http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html#converting-a-math-string-to-other-formats

It works fine for inline equations:

```
\( e=mc^2 \)
```

But an error occurred while creating the SVG in JavaScript :

```
MathJax.mathml2svg("x_2 = y^3")
```

Here is the error:

```
tex-mml-svg.js:1 Uncaught Error: Unknown node type "body"
    at o.error (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at o.makeNode (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at o.compile (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at c.compile (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at T.e.compile (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at Object.renderMath (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at d.renderConvert (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at T.e.convert (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at t.Z.convert (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
    at Object.v.MathJax.<computed> [as mathml2svg] (tex-mml-svg.js:1)
```

Not sure if this is a bug or if I missed something. Here a JSFiddle illustrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/xkud6o73/1/

This is not a duplicate of this question : [Render MathJax in an SVG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862410/render-mathjax-in-an-svg-file)

This question is for older version of MathJax, I'm working with v3.0.0.
As you can see above, my problem is not to create inline SVG but to create string containing the output SVG.

Comment: @Robert Longson The proposed question do not answer to mine. This is not a duplicate. Th eproposed question is for an old version of MathJax. I'm using MathJax v3.0.0 and my problem is not for rendering inline equation . Thanks for removing the duplicate.

Comment: @RobertLongson. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, it has been reported here: 
https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2330

We'll be corrected in MathJax version 3.0.2.

Comment: In fact, this exact question was asked as [issue 2339](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2389) by the same author, and was answered there *before* it was asked here.  @Fifi, why would you ask it again here, when it was already answered there?

Comment: Why your comment is in my answer? Should better be in the question, no?

Comment: I asked on SA first. But as I didn't have any answer and I was not sure if I did something wrong or if it was a bug I also asked on GitHub. Was it a problem?