# Trying to use mathjax in svg

Tags: svg, mathjax

I'm trying to make a svg graphic in my web page. I want to write in it a LaTeX formula using mathjax but it doesn't work. Here is my code, although I think it is not the problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

```
<svg height="250" width="450" > 
<line x1="0" y1="200" x2="450" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" ></line>
<line x1="230" y1="200" x2="230" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
<path d="M 313 200 A 283 283 0 0 0  230 0 l -200 200 m 100 -100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<text x="10" y="30" style="fill:blue;font-size:10px">$\sqrt{2}$</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862410/render-mathjax-in-an-svg-file/14864156#14864156 According to the comments below my answer, mathjax is HTML only.

Comment: @Robert your example in that answer works with MathJax v3 now.

Comment: Well that's nice. I guess you can use it to solve your issue then.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<svg height="250" width="450" > 
  <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="450" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" ></line>
  <line x1="230" y1="200" x2="230" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
  <path d="M 313 200 A 283 283 0 0 0  230 0 l -200 200 m 100 -100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>

  <!--text x="10" y="30" style="fill:blue;font-size:10px">$\sqrt{2}$</text-->
  <foreignObject x="10" y="20" width="100" height="100">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      $$\sqrt{2}$$
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```